# Customer Status is undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a typescript code with simple if else logic

```
endDate: String = '';
customerStatus: String;
this.endDate = this.sampleData.customerStartDate;
if (this.endDate == null) {
this.customerStatus = 'Active';
} else {
this.customerStatus = 'In Active';
}
```

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="card-counter info">
   <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
   <span class="count-numbers">
   <h4 class="margin">{{customerStatus}}</h4></span>
   <span class="count-name"> Customer Status</span>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

If I debug the code then in endDate I can see the value but in CustomerStatus I am getting Undefined and as a result, nothing is being displayed on HTML.
The logic is if the customer has end date then the customer is In-Active or else the customer is Active
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you get your sampleData? From backend or anything else?

Comment: Yeah from the backend.I hit an API and fetch from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not check `null` for `sampleData` object before using `customerStartDate` property.

Because line of code `this.sampleData.customerStartDate` throw exception, the next line of code cant executed.

Edit this line of code, it worked.

```
this.endDate = this.sampleData != null ? this.sampleData.customerStartDate : null;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wefvju

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Can you explain to me what I was doing wrong and how adding this line solved the issue